# Should we keep images on a Lite app in the food delivery domain

Tags: mobile, image

I am doing an exercise to construct a 'lite' mobile app version of an existing food delivery mobile app. I was wondering if it makes sense to show the images of the food items on the app or to remove them and keep just texts (to prevent data usage).

I am of the opinion that the images should stay with an optimization on the technology used to process them. Please suggest if this is a good idea.

Comment: Hi Keval, if your question is about whether it is technically possible to optimize images, then you should direct this question to http://stackoverflow.com. I don't think your question has much to do with UX, unless you are actually going to have a set of users that will be interacting with your mobile app.

Comment: If on Android, have you considered using the [Data Saver](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/data-saver) preference to determine whether to load images for the user or not, or providing a setting within the app itself to enable images?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to give a brief answer. Keep the images and optimize them as much as you can without losing quality.